# A set couple ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

$$\frac{d^2x}{{\rm dt}^2}=-GM\frac{x}{{(x^2+y^2)}^\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{{\rm dt}^2}=-GM\frac{y}{{(x^2+y^2)}^\frac{3}{2}}$$

How can I solve those equations, I tried using wolfram alpha but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

These are the equations for a body in a gravitational field. The solution is obtained via [the Kepler laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=kepler%20law%20planet*%20orbit%20answers%3ayes).